# Missing row using left join and generate_series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't understand why my two table behaves incorrectly, the generated series doesn't show on the joined table.

```
TABLE 1: attendance

id | employee_id | flag | entry_date
-------------------------------
1 | 1 | 0 | 2017-11-17
2 | 2 | 0 | 2017-11-17
3 | 3 | 0 | 2017-11-17
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    attendance.employee_id,
    TO_CHAR(series::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM  generate_series('2017-11-16', '2017-11-30', '1 day'::INTERVAL) series
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      employee_id,
      to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') entry_date
    FROM
        attendance
    WHERE entry_at >= '2017-11-16' AND entry_at <= '2017-11-30'
    GROUP BY to_char(entry_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), employee_id
) attendance ON attendance.entry_date = TO_CHAR(series::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER by employee_id
```

The result is:

```
employee_id | to_char 
------------------------
1 | 2017-11-17
2 | 2017-11-17
3 | 2017-11-17
```

I'm expecting a little bit different in which `2017-11-16` will show since my generated series started at said date.

Expected result:

```
employee_id | to_char 
------------------------
null | 2017-11-16 
null | 2017-11-16
null | 2017-11-16
1 | 2017-11-17
2 | 2017-11-17
3 | 2017-11-17
```

Here's a sample SQL Fiddle to test:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7907/3

Update [Jan/4/2017]: Looks like i'm thinking on the wrong side, I decided to perform a **correlated subquery**

What I wanted to do is to count the **number of dates** present according to the **generated_series**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand, what you really need. What you described as "The result is" - these are rows from your internal query. If you left join generate_series with this internal query - you will get 1 null row for every date excluding 2017-11-17 and 3 rows for 2017-11-17. I checked it - it worked as expected:

```
 employee_id |  to_char
-------------+------------
           1 | 2017-11-17
           2 | 2017-11-17
           3 | 2017-11-17
             | 2017-11-20
             | 2017-11-21
             | 2017-11-22
             | 2017-11-23
             | 2017-11-24
             | 2017-11-25
             | 2017-11-26
             | 2017-11-27
             | 2017-11-28
             | 2017-11-29
             | 2017-11-16
             | 2017-11-30
             | 2017-11-18
             | 2017-11-19
```

Comment: I have different dataset from attendance, what I don't understand is not all dates are joined in generate_series. I must be missing something. Since the result from attendance may vary from time to time.

Comment: What's even weird is when I try to put where `employee_id = 2` inside the left join's subquery it show all the generated series.

Comment: I get the same results as Tomasz, which includes the joined dates and all from the generated series. (assuming entry_at is entry_date)

Comment: Which one is missing? I changed "order by" to "series" and I can't s any date missing in your fiddle.

Comment: Even in your original fiddle - dates which don't have corresponding rows in internal query - are on bottom with "null" in employee_id.

Comment: If you check `employee_id = 17` the dates are not complete.

Comment: @TomaszMyrta I was hoping that every employee is joined with the generated_series.

Comment: If you want to join every employee x every generated_series, than use "cross join" instead of "left join on ()"

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example of using the cross join in the fiddle? I tried various kinds of joins but no luck. Thankyou for your time.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7907/8
Do you need extra rows with employee_id=NULL? - because cross join query doesn't have them.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I was planning to have extra rows and perform some reporting checks. I'm really wrapping my head on this one.

Comment: You can add null rows by combining queries using "union all": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7907/11